# Should I create 2 indexes for the same column to speed up a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, query-optimization

I am new to database index and I've just read about what an index is, differences between clustered and non clustered and what composite index is.

So for a inner join query like this:

```
SELECT columnA
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.columnA= table2.columnA;
```

In order to speed up the `join`, should I create 2 indexes, one for `table1.columnA` and the other for `table2.columnA` , or just creating 1 index for `table1` or `table2`?

One is good enough? I don't get it, for example, if I select some data from `table2` first and based on the result to join on `columnA`, then I am looping through results one by one from `table2`, then an index from `table2.columnA` is totally useless here, because I don't need to find anything in `table2` now. So I am needing a index for `table1.columnA`.

And vice versa, I need a `table2.columnA` if I select some results from `table1` first and want to join on `columnA`.

Well, I don't know how in reality "select xxxx first then join based on ..." looks like, but that scenario just came into my mind. It would be much appreciated if someone could also give a simple example.

Comment: Usually an index on one of the tables is sufficient, but you might find that two indexes are even better.  Test on your data and see what works best.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Let me add a little bit more details.

Comment: Think about which table would make a better driving table for a nested loop here: if it starts with Table1 will it get a small number of rows which would return a lot less rows in Table2 than reading all of Table2 first? Will it be about the same because every row in either table has a matching row in the other? MySQL can do hash joins (at last) so maybe a nested loop isn't the best idea but an index on the columns could give the DB a lot smaller amount of data to read (just the whole index rather than the whole table). Your actual query could also be rewritten to use `intersect`.

Comment: @AndrewSayer MySQL does not support the `insersect` keyword or operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One index is sufficient, but the question is which one?

It depends on how the MySQL optimizer decides to order the tables in the join.

For an inner join, the results are the same for `table1 INNER JOIN table2` versus `table2 INNER JOIN table1`, so the optimizer may choose to change the order. It is not constrained to join the tables in the order you specified them in your query.

The difference from an indexing perspective is whether it will first loop over rows of table1, and do lookups to find matching rows in table2, or vice-versa: loop over rows of table2 and do lookups to find rows in table1.

MySQL does joins as "nested loops". It's as if you had written code in your favorite language like this:

```
foreach row in table1 {
  look up rows in table2 matching table1.column_name
}
```

This lookup will make use of the index in table2. An index in table1 is not relevant to this example, since your query is scanning every row of table1 anyway.

How can you tell which table order is used? You can use `EXPLAIN`. It will show you a row for each table reference in the query, and it will present them in the join order.

Keep in mind the presence of an index in either table may influence the optimizer's choice of how to order the tables. It will try to pick the table order that results in the least expensive query.

So maybe it doesn't matter which table you add the index to, because whichever one you put the index on will become the second table in the join order, because it makes it more efficient to do the lookup that way. Use EXPLAIN to find out.

Comment: Incredibly brilliant explanation! Your answer is what exactly I am thinking about! One thing I want to make sure: so for `inner join`, it's the same whichever table I put the `columnA` index on, do I get this right?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to check what the optimizer does. That should be your takeaway from this discussion.

Answer (score -1):

90% of the time in a properly designed relational database, one of the two columns you join together is a primary key, and so should have a clustered index built for it.

So as long as you're in that case, you don't need to do anything at all. The only reason to add additional non-clustered indices is if you're also further filtering the join with a `where` clause at the end of your statement, you need to make sure both the join columns and the filtered columns are in a correct index together (ie correct sort order, etc).